# How to retrieve records using select statement in while loop in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a 2 tables called `Product` and `ProductDetails`.

My criteria are quite difficult. I don't know how to make it.

So again move `ProductDetails` record to temp table, now balance is 15-12 = 3, now check with 3rd transferred quantity 10,  now 3 < 10 is true. now store this record also to temp table

Can you give any idea to solve this?

Comment: Why do you want to use a `WHILE` loop? SQL Server excels at set based methods, not iterative tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the most recent dates whose cumulative quantity in `productdetails` meets or exceeds the quantity i `product`.  That is a cumulative sum and `join`:

```
select pd.*
from (select pd.*,
             sum(Quantity) over (partition by ProductID       order by DateTransferred desc) as running_quantity
      from productdetails pd
     ) pd join
     product p
     on p.productid = pd.productid and
        p.quantity >= (pd.runningquantity - pd.quantity);
```